# Is it possible to edit a program without the source code?

Tags: c#, .net

My doctor uses software in his practice. He is always annoyed about the focus in one form. When he heard that I was a junior developer, he asked me if I could change the focus of the text field to another text field but i have no source code. only the exe. Is there a possibility with any tools to change the program?

Comment: Technically, yes - but you probably shouldn't unless you understand the implications. #1 is that the license most probably prevents you from doing so - so it would be illegal. #2 is that you are likely to break the program unless you understand it completely

Comment: First check license of the application. I bet that's decompilation is illegal.

Comment: Interacting with a UI is a job for a macro program like AutoHotKey, not for decompiling the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst in theory this might be possible, I would **strongly** advise against it.

You trying to de-compile the exe, figure it out what to change, and then re-compile, is unlikely to end well. De-compiling doesn't magically get you the original source - you get *something*, but it's likely to be extremely difficult to comprehend. Even if you get as far as successful re-compilation, you have as much chance of breaking the program completely, or introducing unexpected bugs, as you have of fixing the specific issue.

And anyway if you did that you'd immediately invalidate any support you did have from the vendor, as well as probably breaking the license conditions, and most importantly you're potentially putting patients at risk by screwing up the software accidentally.

None of those risks are worth taking just for a bit of irritation over setting the focus in a form. Maybe instead you can just take a look at the GUI and see if it's possible for the doctor to quickly and easily use the tab key to move the focus to the other field without too much friction - most forms should support that if they're written in a good way.

And at the end of the day it would make more sense for the doctor to raise a feature request with the makers / vendors of the software (to either change the default, or at least introduce an option so it can be configured).